# Developing Ruby on Rails or any other type of application in XCode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode

Not sure if this is the right stack to be asking this question, but I recently downloaded the XCode 4 preview and would like to do my RoR development in that. I know it was possible in earlier versions but can't seem to get it to happen in 4. Does anyone have any suggestions on where I could look to get it figured out?

Comment: Could you expand on the problem you are having? "Can't get it to happen" covers a multitude of problems! It's just a text editor, so I'm assuming it's a problem with the Organiser?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the vagueness. I read here http://developer.apple.com/tools/developonrailsleopard.html that you could open the organizer and drop the project folder into the left pane and it would open the site for editing. in XCode 4 nothing happens when I drop the project directory. I tried creating a new project but there are only options to create a Mac OSX or iOS project.

Comment: That article is for XCode 3, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a 'Workspace' and then you can drop files into the pane.