# Does Xcode 4 support ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode4

Does Xcode 4 have support for rails projects?  If so, to what extent?

UPDATE - Obviously it lets you edit text files.  But does it give you any IDE features, e.g. syntax highlighting, navigation to declarations, code completion, etc... ?

Comment: There's [this article](http://developer.apple.com/tools/developonrailsleopard.html) which discusses RoR in XCode 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing Ruby on Rails or any other type of application in XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209081/developing-ruby-on-rails-or-any-other-type-of-application-in-xcode)

Comment: The article you mention is XCode3 specific - I need to know about v4.

Comment: Great question. I know xcode3 didn't have deep support for Rails API (or ruby). I'm actually looking for this myself. I've been in obj-c for months for iPhone and with going back to textmate for rails, well, I really miss xcode. Sort of wondering if I'm not the only one...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I paid up to intall XCode 4 thinking that it would be simpler to consolidate all my development to a single IDE. XCode is the default because of the built in Mac API docs. I built a few MacRuby (0.10) samples, which parse and run.

Problems are:

1. XCode insists on using // to comment lines, which then don't parse.
2. There is no debugging for Ruby files, only for the Objective C wrapper stub.
3. There is no in-app "run" for rack, rails or scripting type apps.
4. The syntax parsing is limited to keywords, strings, comments and characters.
5. XCode doesn't understand .erb or .yaml files are html and ruby.

There were [workarounds](http://www.arklyffe.com/main/2010/08/29/xcode-for-ruby-pt-2/) for 1 and 5 in 3.2 for 1 and 5 but they no longer work with 4 as far as I can see.

On the plus side, the documentation interface to OSX and NextStep is very nice and MacRuby and the UI editor work well together and allow bundling desktop apps which can be distributed standalone or via the app store. I would use it to build ruby apps that use the desktop GUI.

For conventional web or scripting apps you can 'bare edit' rails projects in the 'Workspace' area and then skip to the terminal to run a server or use script/console to debug; but for this NetBeans is still far superior IMHO with in-code debugging and automated tests and workflow.

Comment: You can get ruby comments if you change "Editor/Syntax Coloring" to Ruby.  But the IDE does not remember your preference when its closed. So, it kind of sucks and the documentation is not very useful.  It's better than other simple text editors but that's about it.

Answer (score 11):

In the past Xcode releases many were able to use the Xcode IDE for non-apple projects such as PHP, Rails, etc.

All you had to do was open Xcode organiser and drag your project in there and it worked. Not so with Xcode 4, but the feature has not been removed but in fact improved in my opinion.

In Xcode 4, click File > New > New Workspace.

Give it a name and once on the main editor window simply drag and drop your Rails, PHP, etc project onto the project navigator.

Then you can choose Editor > Syntax Coloring > [Any] for syntax highlighting.

M.

Comment: This isn't the same as what Xcode 3 supported.  Xcode 3 let the directory hierarchy rule the organization and didn't impose any "structure" around that.  It looks like Xcode 4 has done away with that, and is using something more like an Eclipse view of the world.  Too heavy for my tastes.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm unable to respond to the comments I'll just give answering your question a shot: Considering [Apple's "what's new" page](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html) doesn't seem to list too many groundbreaking changes, I'm guessing Matt Ball's suggestion to go with [the guide for Leopard](http://developer.apple.com/tools/developonrailsleopard.html) and assuming nothing Rails or Ruby specific is new would be a safe and probably spot-on bet.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a try to xcode 4 with rails. Work fine, except some color syntaxing trouble (with yml  or haml file for example). It's great, expecialy the integration of git (to show easyly modified files)